# JSON retornando valor undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Galera, estou com um código onde recebo os dados JSON, porém ao mostrar está como undefined.

```
function usuario_search(id){  $.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: "/usuarios/search/"+id,
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
        alert(data);
        document.getElementById('name').value = json.name;
        document.getElementById('email').value = json.email;
        document.getElementById('permission').value = json.role;
        $('#defaultModal').modal('show');
      },
      error: function(ts){
        $("#error").text(ts.responseText);
      }});}
```

alert com os dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que aparece no modal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

debugger:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca um debugger; e ve o retorno, dependendo como foi feito no server ele vem como retorno.data no seu caso seria data.data

Comment: editei a publicação, olha lá

Comment: Você percebeu que json é um array?

Comment: tentou `document.getElementById("name").value = json[0].name;` ?

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett Muito obrigado! Consegui, estou iniciando Ajax, mas muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque a variável json é um array:
Para acessar os valores é necessário acessar o índice primeiro, por exemplo:

```js
var json = [ 
    { 
        "email": "admin@mail.com",
        "name": "Admnistrador",
        "role": "Administrador"
    }
];
console.log(json[0].name);
```

**Nota**

Se você pretende utilizar apenas 1 usuário, **não há necessidade de retornar em array**; também **não** recomendo utilizar no código o acesso direto ao índice `json[0].name` . Isso é apenas um exemplo de como você pode obter o valor com o json atual